# Stop Volley from sending cache headers

Tags: android, caching, header, android-volley

Volley keeps sending `If-Modified-Since` header.

I need to stop volley from sending this header because it keeps messing with a response from a third party server. How do I stop volley from sending cache headers?

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me if my answer works for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

In `BasicNetwork.java`, you will find

```
private void addCacheHeaders(Map<String, String> headers, Cache.Entry entry) {
        // If there's no cache entry, we're done.
        if (entry == null) {
            return;
        }

    if (entry.etag != null) {
        headers.put("If-None-Match", entry.etag);
    }

    if (entry.lastModified > 0) {
        Date refTime = new Date(entry.lastModified);
        headers.put("If-Modified-Since", DateUtils.formatDate(refTime));
    }
}
```

So I think you can try one of the following ways:

- Call `setShouldCache(false);`, for example: `jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);`
- Create a custom `BasicNetwork` variable, in which you will override `performRequest` and set `Cache.Entry` variable null or `entry.lastModified <= 0`, can try the following:

  ```
       BasicNetwork basicNetwork = new BasicNetwork(hurlStack) {
           @Override
           public NetworkResponse performRequest(Request<?> request) throws VolleyError {
               request.setCacheEntry(null);
               // request.setShouldCache(false);
               return super.performRequest(request);
          }
       };
  ```

**END OF UPDATE**

IMO you need to override `getHeaders` method, you can try one of the two following ways:

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headerMap = super.getHeaders();
            if (headerMap.containsKey("If-Modified-Since")) {
                headerMap.remove("If-Modified-Since");
            }
            return headerMap;
        }
```

or

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
             Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
             headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
             //...
             //headerMap.put("other keys", "other values");
             //...
             return headerMap;
        }
```

Hope this helps!